# Android: Code Runtime Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am writing a simple calculator, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

LogCat says that the error is in my `onClick`:

```
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
```

But I'm sorry to say I can't find it. So please help me.

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:ems="10" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="Input first number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Input 2nd number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="functionCalculator" 
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="+"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Your result here" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Result"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="-"
        android:onClick="functionCalculator" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`ActivityMain.java`:

```
package com.example.caculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText e1,e2;
    TextView t1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        e1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    }

    public void functionCalculator(View view) {
        int number1 , number2 , result;

        if (view.getId()==R.id.button1) {
            number1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
            number2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
            result = number1+number2;
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(result));
        }
        if (view.getId()==R.id.button2) {
            number1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
            number2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
            result = number1-number2;
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(result));
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full log

Comment: Whats the input you are giving to `e1` and `e2`(if any)?

Comment: @Shaishav input only e1 and e2

Comment: @SujithNiraikulathan 08-29 14:17:47.195: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 14:17:47.195: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-29 14:17:47.195: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
08-29 14:17:47.195: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-29 14:17:47.195: E/AndroidRuntime(279):

Comment: What does `e1` and `e2` contain? Number, characters, decimal numbers, nothing?

Comment: @Shaishav... Numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and didn't run into any issues as long as I put integers in `e1` and `e2`. As soon as I entered decimal numbers, I ran into exact same issue as you mention. This is because you are trying to parse integers out of the input which may not always be successful and will result in a `NumberFormatException`. You should write your code so that it never crashes no matter what the case. Just assume your users are idiots. Try the code below, it shouldn't crash:

```
public void functionCalculator(View view) {

    try {
        // Firstly checking for integers
        int number1, number2;
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());

        if (view.getId() == R.id.button1)
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(number1 + number2));

        else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2)
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(number1 - number2));

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        float number1, number2;

        try {
            // Now checking for decimals
            number1 = Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());
            number2 = Float.parseFloat(e2.getText().toString());

            if (view.getId() == R.id.button1)
                t1.setText(Float.toString(number1 + number2));

            else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2)
                t1.setText(Float.toString(number1 - number2));

        } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
            // No numbers :(
            Toast.makeText(this, "WTF! Enter number here you dingus!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```